# I dont want title bar of usercontrol in WPF with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I need to open a Screen named EditItemTypeView with codes:

```
    public void EditItemType(DAL.ItemTypeDto itemType)
    {
        EditItemTypeViewModel viewModel = new EditItemTypeViewModel(itemType);
        new WindowManager().ShowDialog(viewModel);
    }
```

The dialog shows with a title bar.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B8RT.png)

I dont need this and what should I do?
The target is to show a dialog (keep top) and is there any other solution on this?

Comment: I dont need the title bar. How to make it disappear?

Comment: Check if there is `WindowStyle` property, try setting it to none.

Comment: you can use WindowManager.ShowPopup(viewModel) instead.

Answer (score 1):

var settings = IDictionary (); you can pass in the necessary items to rid your title bar reference the WindowStyle, ShowDialog(viewmodel, settings);

`settings.Add("WindowStyle", WindowStyle.ToolWindow);`